# Best practice in arranging JS code within dynamic websites

Tags: javascript, server-side

I have the following concern in managing our own written JS code (not js libraries like jquery):

Is it better to relate javascript to html only or to relate it to server side code? means is it better to return JS code from the server side code or to create separate JS file and reference it from the html code or event write it inside html page?

here i want to mention an example:

say i have 2 server side pages, register and login, and say we are using jquery validation plugin (referenced in the html using script tag) which we will use to validate the register and login forms, in that case we need to write the validation JS statement   `$('.login_form').validate();` for the login page and the validation JS statement   `$('.register_form').validate();` for the register page.

so do i need to create 2 js files (login.js, register.js) and add each statement in its js file, or write the code inside the html page itself, or return the js code from each page server side code?

Here my confusion is, if i will create 2 separate file, it will be better to maintain the JS code as it is separate, but as for performance and page loading the browser needs to load extra js file that has only one line statement, in other hand if i want to use server side code to generate JS code, then maintaining JS code will be hard but as for performance wise i guess its better.

So what are your suggestions taking in consideration maintainability and performance?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'd write all the javascript into different files on the server side and link them from the page whilst doing development, but then use something like [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to compact them all into one file that you linked from your html file for your production environment.

This allows you to develop in multiple files and keep your code structured well, but only have the browser download one file and only make one http request in your production environment.

The reason why you don't just have your server-side PHP/Python/Java/whatever write the code directly into the html is because that prevents the browser from caching it. The browser will have to download that code on every page on the site. It's much better if it's all in one external javascript file which has [cache-control headers](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) set.

That way the browser will download your scripts only once, and only on the first page the user sees on your website, then load it from cache on every other page load.